# Can EFCore 7 run inside of a .Net 4.8 WebApp?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Right now I have EFCore 2.2 running inside of a .net 4.8 WebApp, runs great. But looks like we're all the way up to EFCore v7 now... would it be an exercise in futility to upgrade my large model project and it not function properly in the 4.8 WebApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 7.0 targets .NET 6. This means that existing applications that target .NET 6 can continue to do so. Applications targeting older .NET, .NET Core, and .NET Framework versions will need to target .NET 6 or .NET 7 to use EF Core 7.0.

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to know the max supported ("supported" I mean working not the ability to get help) EFCore that will function in 4.8?

Comment: I believe the the latest version of EFCore on .NET 4.8 would be EFCore 3.1. Starting with EFCore 5, it doesn't support .NET Framework any longer

Answer (score 2):

No, EF Core 7 suppors only .NET 6 and .NET 7 according to the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.2).